# OCaml build tool dune installed, but doesn't run

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I recently started learning OCaml, and wanted to install the dune build tool. I used `opam install dune`, then followed the instructions [here](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html). However, when running `dune build hello_world.exe`, I got the following error:

```
The program 'dune' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install whitedune
```

`apt search whitedune` tells me that this has nothing to do with the dune I want.

I double checked that dune was installed and re-ran `opam install dune`, to get the message:

```
[NOTE] Package dune is already installed (current version is 1.2.1).
```

After running `opam remove dune` and `opam install dune`, the problem persists.

I am running Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki.

Thank you!

Comment: did you type `eval $(opam config env)` in your shell?

Comment: @PatJ Apparently not. Thank you very much! (I thought it was in my .bashrc, but it wasn't. Big oof moment right there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to run `eval $(opam config env)`. Oops.

Comment: @JakubMuda I am the author of the question. I’m confused as to why there is a problem with this answer. I’m not asking myself for clarification. If there is a problem with the answer or the question, I would like to know.